# A page can have only one server-side Form tag Issue

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a masterpage like this

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/XmasShop.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContents" runat="server">
    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ID="lview1">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <div class="confirmation-cantainer">
                <div class="confirm-01">
                    <form runat="server">
                        <umbraco:Macro Alias="[Xmas]ShopConfirm" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphAuthenticationPane" runat="server">
    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ID="lview12">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <form runat="server">
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="lslougout" runat="server" Style="float: right; color: #003263; text-decoration: none;" text="Logout"></asp:LoginStatus>
            </form>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</asp:Content>
```

And you can see I have two form tags in it,but both are seperate not nested.Still I am getting an error

```
A page can have only one server-side Form tag.
```

Can any one suggest me a solution.When I tried to remove one of the forms its throwing an error elements must be inside a form tag and when I add form above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following tutorial to set up two form tags and be able to toggle them on and off, as required:

http://jerschneid.blogspot.com/2007/03/hide-form-tag-but-leave-content.html

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to have the login information on a separate page.  You could also look into using an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred due to use of more than one

```
<form runnat="server">
```

tag.
Remove one of the form tag.

[This would be more clear by visiting this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/715581.aspx?%20System%20Web%20HttpException%20A%20page%20can%20have%20only%20one%20server%20side%20Form%20tag%20)

Comment: it's about nested tags, and I have already told in my question that I am not using nested forms, Two forms inside a page is allowed, if its not nested